# Show that the cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra can be written into a countable union of some $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, solution-verification

Denote $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}$ to be the set of functions $x:\mathbb{T}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$, where $\mathbb{T}$ is an indexing set (the "time" in the stochastic process).

Now, define the cylinder sets as $$C(t_{1},\cdots, t_{n}, B):=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}:(x_{t_{1}},\cdots, x_{t_{n}})\in B\}\ \text{for some}\ B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n}).$$

Then the cylindrical $\sigma$-algebra is defined as $$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}})=\sigma(\text{cylinders}).$$

Now, I want to show that:

> Define $\mathcal{F}_{T}:=\sigma\Big(\{C(t_{1},\cdots, t_{n}, B):t_{1}\cdots, t_{n}\in T\}\Big)$ for $T\subset\mathbb{T}$. Prove that $$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}})=\bigcup_{\text{countable}\ T\subset\mathbb{T}}\mathcal{F}_{T},$$ where the union is taking over all countable subset $T$ of $\mathbb{T}$.

I had some attempt as follows:

Denote $\mathcal{C}$ to be the collection of all cylinder sets. Let $A$ be a cylinder set, then it can be written as $A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}:(x_{t_{1}},\cdots, x_{t_{n}})\in B\}$ for some $B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$. Then $t_{1},\cdots, t_{n}$ must belong to some index subset $T_{1}$ of $\mathbb{T}$, and thus $$A\subset \{C(t_{1},\cdots, t_{n}, B):t_{1},\cdots, t_{n}\in T_{1}\}.$$

Thus, if we define $\mathcal{C}_{T_{1}}$ to be the collection of all the set of the form as the RHS of the above inclusion, we then have $$\mathcal{C}\subset\mathcal{C}_{T_{1}}\subset\mathcal{F}_{T_{1}}.$$

But $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n}):=\sigma(\mathcal{C})$ is the smallest $\sigma-$algebra containing $\mathcal{C}$, and thus $$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\subset\mathcal{F}_{T_{1}}\subset\bigcup_{\text{countable T}\subset\mathbb{T}}\mathcal{F}_{T}.$$

**However, I have no idea about how to show the inverse inclusion.**

**Also, is my proof for $\subset$ correct? I am really bad at measure theory, so I don't really have any confidence at all...**

This question is related to:

[What is the sigma algebra of cylindrical sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2185980/what-is-the-sigma-algebra-of-cylindrical-sets)

[Cylindrical sigma algebra answers countable questions only.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/373297/cylindrical-sigma-algebra-answers-countable-questions-only),

but there were not any complete proof there, and the notions of cylindrical $\sigma-$algebra were not really the same.

Thank you so much!

**Edit 1:**

As comments pointed out, I should prove $\bigcup_{T}\mathcal{F}_{T}$ is a $\sigma-$algebra. Inspired by **saz**, I generated a proof about $\sigma-$algebra, and seems proved $\subset$. **However,** I still don't know how to show $\supset$.

---

With a little bit notation abuse, denote the RHS of the desired equality to be $\mathcal{F}$.

> Lemma:$\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma-$algebra.

*Proof of lemma:*

Indeed, since $\mathcal{F}_{T}$ is defined to be a $\sigma-$algebra for any countable subset $T\subset\mathbb{T}$, it must contain $\varnothing$, and thus $\varnothing\in\mathcal{F}$.

Secondly, if $E\in \mathcal{F}$, then $E\in\mathcal{F}_{T}$ for some $\mathcal{F}_{T}$, but it is a $\sigma-$algebra, so $E^{c}$ is in that set and thus $E^{c}\in\mathcal{F}$.

Finally, let $\{E_{j}\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ be a countable collection of sets that are in $\mathcal{F}$, then $E_{j}\in\mathcal{F}_{T_{j}}$ for some countable $T_{j}\subset\mathbb{T}$. Consider the set defined by $T^{*}:=\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}T_{j},$ it is again a countable subset of $\mathbb{T}$ because it is a countable union of countable sets. Also, by construction, we must have for each $j$, $$\{C(t_{1},\cdots, t_{n}, B):t_{1}\cdots, t_{n}\in T_{j}\}\subset\{C(t_{1},\cdots, t_{n}, B): t_{1},\cdots, t_{n}\in T^{*}\}\subset\mathcal{F}_{T^{*}},$$ but $\mathcal{F}_{T_{j}}$ is the smallest $\sigma-$algebra containing the LHS, and thus $\mathcal{F}_{T_{j}}\subset\mathcal{F}_{T^{*}}$ for each $j$.

Therefore, $E_{j}\in\mathcal{F}_{T*}$ for each $j$. Hence, $\bigcup_{j=1}^{\infty}E_{j}\subset\mathcal{F}_{T^{*}}\subset\mathcal{F}.$

---

*Proof of $\subset$:*

Now, denote $\mathcal{C}$ to be the collection of all cylinder sets and let $A\in\mathcal{C}$. Then A can be written as $$A=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}:(x_{t_{1}},\cdots, x_{t_{n}})\in B\}\ \text{for some}\ B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n}).$$ But $t_{1},\cdots, t_{n}$ must belong to some countable index subset $T$ of $\mathbb{T}$ (the most convenient way is to define $T:=\{t_{1},\cdots, t_{n}\}$).  Therefore, $A\in\mathcal{F}$, so $\mathcal{C}\subset\mathcal{F}$.

However, we have showed that $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma-$algebra, and we know that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}})=\sigma(\mathcal{C})$ is the smallest $\sigma-$algebra containing $\mathcal{C}$ and thus $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}})\subset\mathcal{F}$.

---

I'd like to express my great appreciate to **saz** who really spent lots of time on my dumb questions. Thank you so much saz :)!

---

**Edit 2: Proof of saz's remark:**

As I am really bad at measure theory, I am going to prove saz's remark as an exercise:

I claim that $\mathcal{F}_{S}\subset\mathcal{F}_{T}$ for any two (not necessarily countable) $S,T\subset\mathbb{T}$ with $S\subset T$.

Indeed, every set in the collection $\mathcal{A}_{1}:=\{C(t_{1},\cdots, t_{n}, B), t_{1}\cdots, t_{n}\in S, B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\}$ must belong the collection $\mathcal{A}_{2}:=\{C(t_{1},\cdots, t_{n}, B), t_{1}\cdots, t_{n}\in T, B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\}$, since $S\subset T$. This implies that $$\mathcal{A}_{1}\subset\mathcal{A}_{2}\subset\sigma(\mathcal{A}_{2})=\mathcal{F}_{T},$$ but $\mathcal{F}_{S}=\sigma(\mathcal{A}_{1})$ is the smallest the $\sigma-$algebra containing $\mathcal{A}_{1}$, and thus $\mathcal{F}_{S}\subset\mathcal{F}_{T}$.

---

It definitely follows immediately from saz's comments about the comparison of generating set.

I am really grateful of the help from saz, thank you so so so much!

Comment: Hint: show that $\bigcup_{T\ \text{countable}} \mathcal F_T$ is a $\sigma$-algebra that contains every cylinder set, and that every $\sigma$-algebra that contains every cyclinder set contains  every $\mathcal F_T$ for countable $T$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael These are exactly what I don't know how to show.....I tried the $\sigma-$agebra part, but I don't know how to show the closure under countable union.

Comment: @JacobsonRadical: Isn't this just a reindexing operation?  A countable union of cylinder sets is going to be in *some* $F_T$, since $T$'s domain is all countable collections.

Comment: @nomen yeah I just edited the exercise I tried to prove, but I am still not sure if the union is taking over countable subset $T$ of $\mathbb{T}$, or the union is taking over countably many subsets $T$ of $\mathbb{T}$.... Let's assume the current version is correct, then I still don't understand why the countable union of cylinder sets is going to be in some $\mathcal{F}_{T}$. Perhaps some cylinder is in another $\mathcal{F}_{T}$? I get the idea about the "countability" here but I cannot convince myself...

Comment: @nomen  even if I can show this, I still don't know how to show the unit contains very cylinder set, and the last statement:"every $\sigma-$algebra that contains every cylinder set contains every $\mathcal{F}_{T}$ for countable $T$.

Comment: In the definition of $\mathcal{F}_{T}$, why is the set of time index finite?

Comment: @XXX its been a long time and I don't really remember why..

Comment: @XXX ok I guess your confusion comes from that the union is taking over all countable subset but in the definition of $\mathscr{F}_{T}$, the time is finite. Its not that. So, the set $\{C(t_{1},\cdots, t_{n},B):t_{1},\cdots, t_{n}\in T\}$ is ranging over all the choice of $t_{1},\cdots, t_{n}\in T$, so for a fixed $t_{1},\cdots, t_{n}$ you have a cylinder, and you can pick another finite set of elements in $T$ forms another cylinder. So the set is actually pretty big, it includes all the cylinder with respect to all the finite choices of $t_{1},\cdots, t_{n}$ from $T$

Comment: @ JacobsonRadical No, I mean that in $\left\{C\left(t_{1}, \cdots, t_{n}, B\right): t_{1}, \cdots, t_{n} \in T\right\}$, ${t_{1}, \cdots, t_{n}}$ can be countable instead of just being finite.

Comment: @XXX I guess thats the definition of cylinder at least for me. The time index set is countable, but you take finitely many of time from $T$ to define a cylinder.

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Sure, but here $\mathcal{B}\left(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}}\right)=\bigcup_{\text {countable } T \subset \mathbb{T}} \mathcal{F}_{T}$ you take $T$ to be countable and I am not sure how to show that $\mathcal{F}_{T}$ is contained in the LHS, when $T$ is infinite.

Comment: @XXX oh I think the answer below solved this direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof of "$\subseteq$" looks okay now. Isn't the converse actually trivial? By definition,

$$\mathcal{F}_T = \sigma(C(t_1,\ldots,t_n,B); t_1,\ldots,t_n \in T, B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)),$$

and so

$$\mathcal{F}_T \subseteq \sigma(C(t_1,\ldots,t_n,B); t_1,\ldots,t_n \in \mathbb{T}, B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)) \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^T).$$

Hence, $\mathcal{F}_T \subseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}})$ for each $T \subseteq \mathbb{T}$, and this gives $\bigcup_{T \, \text{ctble}} \mathcal{F}_T \subseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{T}})$.

**Remark:** What we used here (and what you also used in the proof of closedness of $\mathcal{F}$ under countable unions) is that $\mathcal{F}_S \subseteq \mathcal{F}_T$ for any two $S,T \subseteq \mathbb{T}$ with $S \subseteq T$ (no matter whether the sets $S,T$ are countable or not).

Comment: Nice Remark!! I was thinking about something like this. Since I am really bad at measure theory, I am gonna write a proof about your remark in my edit.

Comment: @JacobsonRadical Yeah, your proof (in the comment, which you deleted) look fine. If you want to put it a different way: the generator of $\mathcal{F}_S$ is smaller than the generator of $\mathcal{F}_T$ and this implies $\mathcal{F}_S \subseteq \mathcal{F}_T$.

Comment: WOW. You are definitely right. Thank you! :)

Comment: @JacobsonRadical You are welcome. I hope I didn't confuse you too much with my previous (misleading) answer.

Comment: Nono, definitely not. That answer actually inspired me to prove out that $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma-$algebra. I am just not comfortable with the "projection" and "topological space" argument. I know there are someways to define cylinder and corresponding $\sigma-$algebra using the projection and so forth, but since I learned the cylindrical $\sigma-$algebra directly from the definition I gave in the post, I don't have too much background for such a construction. It seems that my definition is more strait forward, but leaving many things hard to prove  :(